# Cross Platform GeoLocation compiler issue with standard code

Tags: c#, ios, plugins, xamarin, geolocation

I am working on integrating the [geolocator plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Geolocator) into my Xamarin.Forms app. I have installed the nuget package into .core, .droid & .ios. I haven't added it the the other projects in the solution, as I am on mac and they aren't supported.

I have added the example snippet (less the print to console lines), but it is throwing compiler errors. I have added `using Geolocator;` at the top, but the `var position` line throws error - `the 'await' operator can only be used when its containing method is marked with the 'async' modifier` - What have I done wrong?

I have included a screen shot below:

[![Compiler Errors][1]][1]

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

## UPDATE

My code now runs, I have the following structure:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {

    // Class Definitions 

    public HomePage(IAdapter adapter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.adapter = adapter;

        var LocManager = new CLLocationManager();
        LocManager.AuthorizationChanged += (sender, args) => {
            Debug.WriteLine ("Authorization changed to: {0}", args.Status);
        };
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8,0))
            LocManager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();

        NewDeviceButton.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
           //Code which I would like to be able to use GetLatitude.
       }
    }

    async Task<double> GetLongitude()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

        var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
        var longitude = position.Longitude;
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error message. 
`On iOS 8.0 and higher you must set either NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your Info.plist file to enable Authorization Requests for Location updates!` I originally only had the async method, but having seen the error message and reading your app note, I added the additional code at the top to try and authorise location services. However, I now get an error message saying `Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CLLocationManager' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246)` this shows on the var LocManager line. Why is this and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: please do NOT post code snippets as images.  They are difficult to read and make it impossible for search engines to index.

Comment: @Jason apologies, only did it as an extra thing, as I find it sometimes helps. I also referenced the error in code for the search engines.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal an await method need to be run in an async method.

Therefore, you need to call your method in the OS projects.

Here the steps to work with geolocator plugin :

Create an interface on your xamarin form project:

```
public interface ILocation
    {
        Task<Position> GetLocation();
    }
```

Create a class in your OS project ( Android, IOS or WP )

Here the exemple for Android

```
public class Location_Android : Activity, ILocation
    {
        public async Task<Position> GetLocation()
        {
            return await GetPosition();

        }

        private async Task<Position> GetPosition()
        {
            Position result = null;
            try
            {
                var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
                if (locator.IsListening != true)
                {
                    locator.StartListening(minTime: 1000, minDistance: 0);
                }
                var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(10000);
                //You can use Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position
                //Here I use a personnal class
                result = new Position(position.Longitude, position.Latitude);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Debug("GeolocatorError", e.ToString());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

On your class call the method like that

```
var position = await DependencyService.Get<ILocation>().GetLocation();
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: But I don't understand why the tutorial code on the github pages doesn't work as it says it should?

Comment: that code is just a small snippet - it assumes you understand enough C# to include that snippet in your own project.  The problems in your example stem from basic C# issues - trying to execute code outside of a method, and improper use of await.

Comment: The GetLocationAsync is a method and that has to be called from within another method that is marked with an async keyword.  What OrcusZ mentioned here is a bit much for what is needed really. You just need to call the GetLocationAsync from inside of some method for isntance a click handler: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/blob/master/TestProject/TestAppForms/TestAppForms/TestAppForms/Pages/GeolocatorPage.xaml.cs#L16-L32

Comment: @JamesMontemagno How do I get around the `On iOS 8.0 and higher you must set either NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in your Info.plist file to enable Authorization Requests for Location updates!` response? I have written up my problem in the question.

Comment: In iOS 8 you now have to call either RequestWhenInUseAuthorization or RequestAlwaysAuthorization on the location manager (the plugin does this automatically for you, however, need to add either the concisely named NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to your Info.plist.

Go to your info.plist and under source add one of these flags: http://screencast.com/t/YEeuAYMBBJ

For more info: http://motzcod.es/post/97662738237/scanning-for-ibeacons-in-ios-8